# Maximum magnitude subset sum

Tags: combinatorial-optimization

Let $z_1,z_2,\dots,z_N$ be vectors from $\mathbb Z^m$ for some $m$.  The problem is:

Given a positive integer $p$, find the subset $A_p \subset \{ 1,2,\dots,N \}$ of size $|A_p| = p$ such that
$$
\|\sum_{i \in A_p} z_i \|
$$
is maximized, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm.

I am most interested in cases where $m$ is small, not much more than $2$, and $N$ is large, potentially $1000$s.

I would be surprised if this problem had not previously been studied.  Has anybody seen it before?  Does it have a name?

Comment: A starting point would be to start looking at work on column subset selection, see e.g., http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.0127

Comment: You should probably have the vectors be from $\mathbb{Z}^m$ (to avoid there being no computable solution).

Comment: @Ricky Thanks, I've made that change.

Comment: @Gerry My bad, I obviously mean positive integer!  Fixed.